# How do I perform sequential ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a button `button1` and once it is clicked it redirects to a url `www.first.com`. This url contains another url in its response `www.second.com`. I intercept the request with ajax call and instead of redirecting to `www.first.com` I redirect to `www.second.com`. The following code works perfectly fine, and does what I expect it to do:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.first.com',
    method: 'GET',
    crossDomain : true,
    success: function(response){
      //here I am redirected to www.second.com
      window.location.href = response;
     }
  });
});
```

I want to do another ajax request - the page `www.second.com` authomaticaly gets redirected to `www.third.com`. I dont want to do some simple string manipulation on the url (lets say I want to change it to `www.third2.com`) and then to redirect directly to `www.third2.com`. How do I do that? I guess I need another ajax call but I dont know how to make it run sequentially after finishing the first one.

Posting what I have tried so far and what didnt work:

```
success: function(response){
     $.ajax({
        url: response,
        method: 'GET',
        crossDomain : true,
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: false
        },
        success: function(result2){
          //it does not redirect to `google.com`; it still redirects to `www.second.com`
          result2 = "https://www.google.com/";
          window.location.href = result2;
          alert("This alert does not show");
        }
      });
      //maybe I have to remove this line? 
      window.location.href = response;
     },
```

Comment: You're missing a comma in `url: 'http://www.first.com,`

Comment: if "*the page `www.second.com` authomaticaly gets redirected to `www.third.com`*" then you'll have no problem as the browser will handle the `301`/`302` response

Comment: *Sounds like* an XY problem where you "get" second.com and instead of returning a page it returns some text to go to third.com - when it should just return a 301/302 with the new url directly.

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried to put another ajax function inside my `success` function but it didnt work

Comment: How do you know if it's a redirect or not?  Will it always be first/second->third?  What if second is *not* a redirect, or third is also a redirect?  That's what setting the correct response on the server is for and `$.ajax` will handle it.  Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @freedomn-m it does redirect to the third page and returns status 302. But before going to the thir page, I want to edit the url. s.t. I redirect to `www.third2.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make another ajax request inside your first request callback, like this:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.first.com',
    method: 'GET',
    crossDomain : true,
    xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: false
    },
    success: function(response){
      $.ajax({
        url: response,
        method: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: false
        }
      },
      success: function(response2){
        window.location.href = response2;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

It's not pretty though, but you can get cleaner code using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for instance.

Comment: I think you would need to remove the `window.location.href = response;` because it will be executed _before_ your callback.

Comment: I did remove it, and yet, no redirection happens

Comment: If you go to the devtools and inspect the network, do you see the second request with its response?

Comment: I see that `www.second.com` is being called with status 302 and that `www.third.com` is being called with status 302

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you aren't intercepting a redirect.  You are making an outbound request on a button click.  I only point this out so that we are speaking the same language.  Because, once you do get your secondary URL, you ARE redirecting to that location.

So, your answer is dependent on what you're really trying to accomplish.  If you simply want to take the returned URL and make another AJAX request to it (and either manipulate it, redirect to it, or both), just nest the secondary request within your `success` function.

However, if you want to redirect to this second location AND THEN make a subsequent request, this is more complicated.  You will have to make sure that the page represented by the second URL has an on-load method that makes either another AJAX request or a page-redirect, whichever you are trying to accomplish.  Once you set your `window.location.href` (after getting that second URL), the browser is going to attempt to redirect.  Any on-page-unload events are going to be unreliable, browser-to-browser (in my experience).